# Elementor Pro Form - skip form action (Mailerlite) if field is empty and send form

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, elementor

I'm using Elementor Pro Forms to create a simple form with MailerLite integration.

I'm using: "Collect submissions" and "MailerLite" after submit.

What I'm trying to do is skip "MailerLite" action if value (input) is empty and then send submission to elementor.

My code is:

```
add_action( 'elementor_pro/forms/validation', function ( $record, $ajax_handler ) {
  $form_name = $record->get_form_settings( 'form_name' );

  if ( 'my_el_form' !== $form_name ) {
    return;
  }

  $fields = $record->get_field( [
    'id' => 'emailval',
  ]);

  if ( empty( $fields ) ) {
    return;
  }

  $field = current( $fields );

  if ( '' ===  $field['value']  ) {
    //if value is empty skip mailerlite and send form
  }
}, 10, 2 );
```

Thanks for advice.